# When GAE SetHandler is invoked first time, it is called twice instead of once

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Below is a *minimal Python example* showing *adding* one entity to NDB, but the adding method is actually *being called twice* (the entity appears twice in `Datastore Viewer` and debug lines).

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class GetHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "GetHandler:get!"

class SetHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print 'SetHandler:get!'

def main():
    print 'main!'
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
            ('/get', GetHandler),
            ('/set', SetHandler)],
            debug=False) 
    global app
    app = application
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == 'main':
    main()
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

The steps I take:

1. I start with a cleared `Datastore` and `Memcache.`
2. I enter `http://localhost:8080/set?name=x&value=88` in my browser.
3. As seen in the debug lines, `SetHandler` is called twice `(SetHandler:get!` is printed twice):

---

```
$ dev_appserver.py .
INFO     2016-10-22 09:55:35,298 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-10-22 09:55:35,389 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:32980
INFO     2016-10-22 09:55:35,395 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-10-22 09:55:35,395 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
main!
SetHandler:get!
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache

SetHandler:get!
INFO     2016-10-22 09:56:41,585 module.py:788] default: "GET /set?name=x&value=88 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Note: above happens only on the first invocation of `SetHandler.` All subsequent `SetHandler` invocations behave as expected (i.e., called once - executed once).

### Can I change something so when `SetHandler` is invoked for the first time, it'll be called only once and not twice?

Comment: have a look in the quickstart: Hello World : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two wsgi handlers one in main and one declared in the app.yaml.
You don't need to call run_wsgi_app in the main just declare the app variable in the global scope like so:

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
            ('/get', GetHandler),
            ('/set', SetHandler)],
            debug=False)
```

Side point: using GET in order to set value is bad practice, use POST or PUT instead.

Comment: Thanks @shay - for answering on שבת. It's a requirement that I use main(). Which lines should I change in the `app.yaml` so it won't create a WSGI handler?

Comment: @boardrider If you are using standard environment for app engine you have to use app.yaml url handler. Why do you need to use main?

Comment: This is a directive from my boss. BTW, I commented out the whole `handlers` stanza in app.yaml, and (in `localhost` at least) it works as before: the first invocation of SET calls `SetHandler` twice.

Comment: @boardrider how do you run the script? which parameters are you passing?

Comment: @boardrider if you remove the handlers section from app.yaml there is nothing that can route the request to the proper handler

Comment: I'm in the directory where my main,py and app.yaml are, and I execute in bash: `dev_appserver.py .`

Comment: After your comment, @Shay, I redid my stanza commenting, and I must have been in the wrong directory, because - as you suggested - when the `handlers` stanza in app.yaml is commented out, `dev_appserver.py .` fails to start. So, back to my previous query: is there something I can  change in the app.yaml (or elsewhere) so I won't have two WSGI handlers?

Comment: @boardrider go back to your boss and ask him why do you need main? because app engine doesn't work like that. If you really, really need main, just put it in a different script and import the handlers from this module